# Can an ML2032 battery be used in place of a CR2032 battery?

Tags: batteries

I discovered this battery existed earlier when I looked into replacing the battery in my logitech K750 solar charging keyboard. In fact, searching for the ML2032 battery comes up with many specific references to this keyboard.

Given the name and form factor, I assume it has other uses as well, but information on it is surprisingly lacking. One website said that this battery was not for public sale, but only sold directly to OEMs.

I ordered a replacement battery for my K750, but it wasn't possible to order a single one, so I will be receiving a pack of two.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the other battery in place of a CR2032, as I frequently have to replace the one in my doorbell and other appliances. It might actually be cost-effective to buy an ML2032 recharger given how often I seem to replace it, and perhaps nicer for the environment as well? But I digress.

Anyway, my question is simply, can I use the ML2032 in place of the CR2032?

Comment: why don't you refer to cross reference listings ... use google to find them ... anyone that answers your question will do exactly that

Comment: The ML is rechargeable. The CR is not. The main thing to do is to pop up the two datasheets and examine the discharge curves and rates of discharge. If they are sufficiently compatible, you are okay. (Or you could just try them and see.)

Comment: I had a look on google but I don't know what to search for

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ML2032 in any device which accepts CR2032, but you CAN'T use the CR2032 in devices which accept the ML2023, because the CR2032, being non-rechargeable, might EXPLODE when trying to be recharged.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same keyboard, Logitech K750,that uses the ML2032 battery.  ML2032 is rechargeable in this keyboard by the solar panel.

IF you cover the solar panel entirely on the keyboard blocking out ALL light sources, you can use a CR2032 battery TEMPORARILY while you wait for your ordered ML2032 battery to arrive.  The caveat is... that you should turn off the keyboard when not in use or else it might drain the CR2032 battery.  I am presently typing this using the Logitech keyboard, and a CR2032 battery and it works fine.

Of course, if you don't cover the solar panel, the battery WILL EXPLODE as mentioned because the panel tries to recharge a battery that can not be recharged.  Again, this is a temporary workaround for those who need to use the keyboard and can't afford the down time on their computer while they wait for delivery of the proper battery.